# Behaviour of Laplace transform as $s \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, laplace-method

I have shown that if $f$ is a continuous function with scaling symmetry given by $f(mt)=m^kf(t)$ for any $m>0$, than $(\mathcal{Lf})(s) = m^{-k-1}(\mathcal{Lf})(\frac{s}{m})$.

For this $f$, what can be said about $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\,dt$ and what is the behaviour of $\mathcal{L}f$ as $s \to \infty$

My initial thought is that the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\,dt$ diverges, because $f$ is defined as a function with scaling symmetry - it increases exponentially and therefore since you integrate on $\mathbb{R_+}$ it will diverge - I'm not sure if that argument is actually correct though.

As for the other part of the question - I think it converges to $0$, because of the definition: $\mathcal{L}(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)\,dt $

Comment: If your condition is true for all $m>0$ and all $t\geq 0$, then actually $f(m) = f(m\cdot 1) = m^k f(1)$, so the functions you are looking at are just $f(t) = c t^k$.

Comment: There's an argument missing from  the identity $(\mathcal{Lf})(s) = m^{-k-1}\frac{s}{m}(\mathcal{Lf})$. The Laplace transform on the RHHS is evaluated  _where_?

Comment: You're indeed right, sorry about that typo... It should be evaluated at $s/m$ and not multiplied by $s/m$ ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you get $f(t)=ct^k$ Fabian? Does this mean that that the integral diverges?
edit: I think I realized why... if $f(t) = ct^k$ we see that $f(mt) = c(mt)^k$  which is the same as $f(mt) = m^k * f(t) = m^k * c*t^k = c(mt)^k$...